# Making text follow your cursor inside a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt, mouselistener

I'm trying to make a particular string of text follow the cursor inside the JPanel. I've created a class that extends JPanel and implements MouseMotionListener. The code does not seem to work. The text is shown, but it doesn't follow the cursor.

```
package followthemouse;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TheJPanel extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener {

    private int x = 20;
    private int y = 20;

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawString("I love your cursor!", x, y);

    }


    @Override
    public void mouseMoved (MouseEvent me)
    {
        x = me.getX();
        y = me.getY();
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged (MouseEvent me)
    {

    }


}
```

Here is what is in the main function :

```
package followthemouse;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 *
 * @author Vikram
 */
public class FollowTheMouse extends JFrame{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TheJPanel y = new TheJPanel();
        JFrame x = new JFrame("The TITLE");
        x.add(y);
        x.setSize(400, 400);
        x.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add the listener to the panel.

Insert the following constructor:

```
public TheJPanel() {
    this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add:

```
addMouseListener(y);
addMouseMotionListener(y);
```

- plus coding this in a separate class would be better I think. You can also extend MouseInputAdapter instead of implementing MouseMotionListener.

Comment: +1. I'm learning the basics and coding in a separate inner class would certainly be more efficient I suppose.